# WPF textbox does not react to input while in DoEvents loop

Tags: wpf, textbox, doevents

For some reason my program needs to pause in a function, while still reacting to user input. This is currently done using `DoEvents` in a loop.

Unfortunately my `textbox` does not work properly while I am in the `DoEvents` loop. I cannot type in it. It seems to get the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events OK, but the `Text` property and the dispaly do not show what I am typing.

To make matters more mysterious it reacts to backspace and Ctrl+V to paste text, just typing in it does not work. It works again OK as soon as I stop the loop.

Any ideas?

Attached is an example demonstrating the problem. Just in case it matters I am using VB on VS2010.

This is the xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTest" Text="Testing" Margin="10"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnStartLoop" Content="Start DoEvents Loop"         
                Click="StartLoop_Click" Margin="10"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnStopLoop" Content="Stop DoEvents Loop" 
                Click="StopLoop_Click" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This is the xaml.vb file:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private stopLoop As Boolean = False

    Private Sub StartLoop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                                ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        stopLoop = False
        LoopFunction()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoopFunction()
        While stopLoop = False
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopLoop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                               ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        stopLoop = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't use Application.DoEvents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use `Application.DoEvents` for this purpose. WPF has its own mechanizm for event processing via `Dispatchers` so I think you should use `Dispatcher` to process messages. Dispatchers have their own message queues and I assume that WPF sends some messages directly to the Dispatcher ignoring Windows message queue.

If you still want to use DoEvents-like hack I would recommend using this instead:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {}), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

And other separate question here is why do you want to use such a hacky approach here? Halting the main thread is not a good idea in Windows world anyway.

Comment: Good question about why I am using the DoEvents loop. I have been wondering whether there would be an alternative approach.    My program is a kind a debugger. The code that executes (a standard C dll) uses callbacks to notify the VB.NET frontend of its progress.   When the user wants to break execution, I need to loop in the frontend without returning from the callback function. I still need to react to user input.   The whole code was ported from VB6, where the Windows message loop was replaced by a message loop within the program.

Comment: I did try adding                `Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, New Action(AddressOf EmptyMethod))`
in the loop, but that didn't help.

Comment: Do you know of an example that uses Dispatchers to process messages instead of using DoEvents?

Comment: @Margarita, http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/04/dispatcher-frames.html. You've used `Render` priority which is pretty high priority (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), you should use lower priority, I think you can choose `ApplicationIdle` for example

Comment: you are a star!! Changing the priority made all the difference. I had used Render, because somewhere else in the progem we use the same line to specifically update the display and I just copied and pasted the line. I might still look a bit more into the Dispatcher to see if I can impriove the design.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(Window)` method, it will make your `wpf` window's control work correctly when use `Winform's DoEvent` fuction.